# EnvironmentObject does not work when sheet is presented

Tags: core-data, swiftui, environment

I have a view that has managedObjectContext(Environment Variable). It works fine when presented in NavigationView with NavigationLink. But it does not work when the view is presented as a sheet.
It gives me an error when I save some entity data.

"The operation couldn’t be completed. (Foundation._GenericObjCError error 0.)"

Is there anything I am missing when using the Environment object. My code

```
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext 

@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sheet is not a child component of the `ContentView`.

Thus, you have to pass this Environment separately to the sheet:

```swift
.sheet(isPresented: self.$isPresented, content: MySheetView().environment(\.self.moc)
```

where `moc` is defined in the View that initiates the sheet as:

```swift
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
```